# Xcode6 Beta7 is unusable?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, beta

I have just downloaded the latest version of Xcode, Xcode-Beta7. However, after it is installed in folder **Applications**, I find it impossible for me to open it. When I try to open it, it just gets itself stuck on the dock. What I can only do is to force quit it.

My OSX version is 10.9.4.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: For me, each Beta took like 15ish minutes sitting in the dock while it was (I assume) silently loading or something.. Have you tried waiting for it to load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be patient.  It does take well over 15-20 minutes to display both the "was downloaded from the Internet, are you sure you want to open it?" prompt and then finally light the "application is running" icon.  If you go into Activity Monitor under CPU during this time you will see that it is there.

Comment: Same thing happened here.

Comment: Yeah. It's basically doing a checksum of 5.28GB of application to make sure it hasn't been interfered with since it was signed. This is *not fast*, especially on more venerable hardware.

Comment: Thanks! But that is ridiculous! Apple should have added an effing progress bar!

Comment: How come then I could use the Beta5 immediately upon install, but this one is doing the checksum?

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but after the xCode6 Beta7 stopped jumping in the dock (still did not open the app), I have the same behavior when trying to unzip a file - the archive icon is just jumping, jumping, jumping.........wtf?